# How to make sure I don't change originals by changing references?

Tags: scala

Disclaimer: I am not sure I explain my question really well. I am happy for suggestions for clarification.

---

Things like

```
val a = DenseVector.ones[Double](2)
val b = a
b(1 to 1) := 2.0
a // return: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(1.0, 2.0)
```

in Scala are kind of an issue for math guys like me, while this is not an issue e.g. in R

```
a = c(1,1)
b = a
b[1] = 2.0
b // return: [1] 1 2
a // return: [1] 1 1
```

I do not know how the above phenomenon is called, but how do I avoid it? If I understand correctly it is avoided by using `val` in all classes **and** immutable collections, where immutable collection sort of a collection is, where each entry is a `val` instead of a `var` in layman's terms. This not-copy-but-reference-issue is also happening when giving a function an object and I am not quite sure what is going to happen to it (side effect, but also when I return it instead of a newly created object). Even `def myfct(val myparameter)` does not guarantee that no `var`s of myparameter are changed, so I should only give parameters that are `val`s exclusively.

All this sounds so error-prone - I am just waiting for me to make some mayor mistakes. Only very rarely I really want to pass a reference to an object and not a deep copy. Are unit-tests really the only way (and even then I have to think of all possible errors that might happen) I can test that I don't forget to make deep copies (explicitly or implicitly by creating a new object)?

How can I make sure I don't make the mistake of changing an original by changing the reference? Is the only answer to use `val` and immutable collections or is there another design pattern? E.g. is there a design pattern where I can make input parameters to a function immutable even if the input is a mutable collection or an object with mutable members?

Comment: Scala is as immutable as you want it to be: if you use immutable structures, they are ... well ... immutable. If you use mutable ones, then they are not. 
I am not sure I understand what your problem is with it. If you don't like stuff that can be mutated, don't use it. Don't make deep copies (they are inefficient, and slow), just use immutable structs whenever makes sense

Comment: `b[1] = 2.0` doesn't look like an operation on immutable object, so it's probably not about immutability. When you use immutable objects your reference problem simply doesn't exist, otherwise most modern OOP languages I know copy references only.

Comment: @Dima: I tried to improve on my question.

Comment: @VictorMoroz: I tried to improve on my question.

Comment: I don't see much of an improvement. It still doesn't make sense.  If you don't want the content of your collection, why is it mutable to begin with???

Comment: @Dima: E.g. because I cannot change the implementation of `DenseVector`. E.g. because the input parameter is an interface, and I don't know how it is implemented.

Comment: @Make42 If the library you are using uses mutable structures, it either has a good reason for it, and you should learn to take advantage of it, or it's just a bad library, and you should look for another one. 
In any case `denseVector.copy` solves your problem here...

Answer (score 1):

Scala allows mutable objects, and it looks like `breeze.linalg.DenseVector` is a mutable object.

However, it also has good support for immutable structures. There's an immutable collections API which has immutable versions of everything:

```
scala> val a = Vector(1,1,1) // note the "scala.collection.immutable namespace"
a: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 1)

scala> val b = a  // not a deep copy, but a shared ref to an immutable object
b: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 1)

// mutating operations on immutable objects will return a modified
// copy, leaving the origin object unchanged
scala> b.updated(1, 2)  
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 1)

scala> b
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 1)

scala> a
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 1)

scala> val c = b.updated(1, 2)
c: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 1)
```

> Only very rarely I really want to pass a reference to an object and not a deep copy.

Scala and other c-family languages don't use deep copies like "R" does. It's more efficient to pass around references than to take defensive copies all the time. If the objects are immutable then copying is only needed on write, not on read.